# Get X most popular tags from query

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "SELECT tag.name, tag.id
        FROM #__k2_tags as tag
        LEFT JOIN #__k2_tags_xref AS xref ON xref.tagID = tag.id
        WHERE xref.itemID IN (".implode(',', $IDs).")
        AND tag.published = 1";
```

in xref.tagID is tag ids eg: tagID:42 is 100 times, tagID:15 is 90 times, tagID:56 is 10 times, I want show first 42 then 15 then 56 (I want cound how many tag is in xref.tagID and order)

Comment: I really hope for your sake that `$IDs` are properly escaped.

Comment: I don't think this can be done with just SQL. I think you will have to get all the data and then use PHP to sort it the way you want it

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
$query = "
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT tag.name, tag.id, count(xref.id) AS tagCount
    FROM #__k2_tags as tag
    LEFT JOIN #__k2_tags_xref AS xref ON xref.tagID = tag.id
    WHERE xref.itemID IN (".implode(',', $IDs).") AND tag.published = 1
    GROUP BY tag.name, tag.id
)
ORDER BY tagCount";
```

The GroupBy in the **subquery** allows you to count the amount of tags occurrences for each tag type.
The **main query** is required to sort by the aggregate value tagCount.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `group by` function :

```
"SELECT  tag.id, count(*)
        FROM #__k2_tags as tag
        LEFT JOIN #__k2_tags_xref AS xref ON xref.tagID = tag.id
        WHERE xref.itemID IN (".implode(',', $IDs).")
        AND tag.published = 1
GROUP BY tag.id";
```